# In java script whats the difference between var a = xyz[] and var a = xyz{}

Tags: javascript, jquery

In java script (or jquery) , what is difference between

```
var a = xyz[] 
var a = xyz{}
```

I searched on internet but couldn't find any answer? please let me know if there is any difference.

Comment: Both are invalid syntax.  for first one it returns `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]` and second one it returns `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }`  check your code to find what is `xyz` holds

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan Nit: `xyz{}` should fail on the `{` token.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's invalid syntax.

```
var a = [];
```

Initializes an array instance.

```
var a = {};
```

Initializes an object instance.

The syntax you describe is invalid.  However, if you have an array `a`, you can access elements of it thusly:

```
a[0]
```

And if you have an object `a`, you can access properties of it the same way:

```
a['propName']
```

You can also access properties with the dot notation:

```
a.propName
```

But if your property contains invalid identifier characters (anything other than a-z, A-Z, $, and _), you *must* use the bracket notation:

```
a['prop name with ## stuff']
```

Note that arrays can have properties and objects can have numeric property names.  This is because arrays *are* objects in JavaScript, albeit special ones that handle numeric properties differently than objects, and have some functionality built in (as well as a `length`) property.